# AJAXing Images and dealing with it's data

Tags: javascript, ajax, image

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "http://img.bitpixels.com/getthumbnail?code=72853&size=200&url=http://www.facebook.com"}).done(function ( data ) {
        if( console && console.log ) {
            magically_display(data)
        }
    });
```

So i've got as far as to ajaxing images. Now im confused, is it possible to display the image without getting a base64 encoded version from the server?
I don't want to use the Image Object to load the image, nor do i want to put the url directly into an image tag, my purpose for this is to find a way to encode the image into a format which i can save in localstorage and later display using javascript.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: you want speed up your application this way ?

Comment: this could be usefull for decreasing requests count and for offline work acceptance

Comment: If this is supposed to be caching to save time and traffic, I think it’s the wrong approach. Managing caching is the job of HTTP, and for local web apps there’s cache manifests.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

```
interface Storage {
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  [IndexGetter] DOMString key(in unsigned long index);
  [NameGetter] DOMString getItem(in DOMString key);
  [NameSetter] void setItem(in DOMString key, in DOMString data);
  [NameDeleter] void removeItem(in DOMString key);
  void clear();
};
```

LocalStorage allows to save only String values. So, you must to "convert" your image to text and "convert it back" for current usecase. Guess, base64 is the best solution.